# With a rep recalculation, will I get my missing rep back?

Tags: support, reputation-recalc

Today, I reached 200 rep, but 20 of them came from a now-deleted post (a duplicate answer posted really close in time to the first answer). I stopped getting rep from my answers after this was deleted and I hit 180 reputation on posted answers today (180 + the 20 from the deleted = the cap of 200).

After a rep recalculation, I will lose the 20 points from that deleted answer (I'm pretty sure). But will the system detect that I made more than 20 points after that and give me any rep from after that?

The only reason I care is because I want to reach 20k before the Boston Dev Days...

Personal Example:

- 200 rep earned to hit cap
- 3 more upvotes for 30 "potential rep"
- Answer deleted wipes out 2 upvotes to drop down to 180 rep.
- Rep limit after recalc **should** come out to 200 with 1 upvote left over due to cap.

Comment: If anyone else can word this better given my comments, please do so. I think it's somewhat confusing.

Comment: Tried to include a more concrete example.

Comment: I get the feeling that rep is **really** important to you.

Comment: Only because I want 20k before Boston Dev Days...if not 25k.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that *in theory* it should work like that, yes.

A few times I've had a rep recalc and still had what appeared to be some oddities. Here's a sample timeline:

- 2am: 5 genuine votes
- 3am: 20 upvotes from one user, hit cap after the first 15 of them
- 6am: Get online, post answers, get more upvotes, report vote fraud
- 10.30am: Votes are removed, 150 points lost
- 11am: Request rep recalc: still not hit rep limit despite having lots of votes

In other words, votes that didn't count due to the rep limit being hit for fraud *appeared* not to count after the rep recalc. I had a summary screen for "today" which showed *less* than 200 rep, but still votes that didn't contribute to reputation.

I'm not overly bothered and it's a very hard thing to diagnose for certain, but that's at least what I *think* I saw. It does sound very odd, based on what a rep recalc is meant to do...

Now, the good news is that all of the votes are recorded so if there *is* a bug in the recalc procedure, when it's fixed and you get another recalc, you'll get the rep back.

I believe the *intended* behaviour is for those "wasted" votes to come back into effect after previously-counted votes are deleted, at least.

Comment: This is indeed how it happened to me after a recalc...not sure if it's supposed to be like this.

Comment: Re sandbox: do you think they'd throw us a stackexchange? ;-p

Comment: @Marc: I've considered that, I have to admit. I'd really like the source, of course :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you should get that rep back. I want to believe that if you got 25 upvotes in a day, you should cap at 200. If you had an answer deleted that subtracted 2 upvotes that left you with 180, you should still in theory have 230 rep worth of upvotes, so during a recalc you should still make the 200 points.

Comment: That's what I'm hoping. I want to get 3k before October 7th...I need to max out 15 times between now and then to make it happen.

Comment: I'd suggest picking a fairly active tag and sticking to it. Also, answer questions even after the cap if you think you can get the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you keep getting rep for today then it will count toward the limit for the day after the recalc. So if you got a total of 220 today but 20 went away in a recalc then you would still get 200 for the day. The system still tracks your rep for the day even after you hit the limit. It just doesn't apply more than 200 per day.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking, I don't think, unless I misunderstand you. If I stopped posting on SO for the rest of the day and there is a rep recalc right now, would I get 200 rep or 180?

Comment: Right now you would get 180.

Comment: But if you keep posting and go beyond the limit by as much as you would lose then you would still get 200.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you **really want**, add a comment here and I'll try it. **However** You'd need to accept that you might actually *lose more rep* from other deleted posts etc.

The other day somebody requesting a rep recalc lost ~450 points.

On your head be it; there is no preview nor undo. Let me know.

Comment: Do it, please. It will help me gauge how much rep I need before October 7th's Dev Days...

Comment: Ahhh!  That was me.  421 point hit from the recalc.  I feel much better now though.

Comment: Ouch!! Ladies and gentlemen, we have a new winner of the "recalc ate my rep", at a whopping -716.

Comment: Wow...that was....intense...however, it did not work as described by TheTXI and others - I was upvoted enough to reach 200 pts today, but I only have 180 rep for today.

Comment: I think I'm going to stop doing recalcs... I can't help thinking somehow I'm going to get the blame...

Comment: Haha, wow!  That is quite a bit!

Comment: Marc, don't worry, I have no negative feelings towards you.

Comment: @Thomas - it sounds exactly as described by Jon, though.

Comment: Did this recalc my rep on SF and SU as well? I'm wondering if a good portion of my rep loss was because of moved questions...I didn't think I had that many deleted questions/answers, but I suppose it's possible.

Comment: Ah!!! Yes, that is entirely possible. Replies to moved questions are essentially deleted. I can only do SO and MSO. TheTXI can do SU; for SF, see "about" (top of page).

Comment: @Marc: It still doesn't explain hitting the limit though. I suspect there's still an issue with rep recalcs. It would be so nice to have a "sandbox" SO to just test this stuff out with :)

Answer (score 0):

I think so, a rep recalc computes all your reputation from scratch, so the rep cap would be taken into account without counting the now deleted post and you'd get the reputation from the subsequent posts