# Will a moderator know if I flag them?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, flags, moderator-abilities

This is related to [Kev's recently posted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15947/is-flagging-anonymous).  Bill the Lizard informed us that mods know who flagged a post, but does this include them?  If a mod gets flagged, do they get to see who flagged them?  Not that any of these wonderful mods would ever think of doing anything untoward, but you never know.  Bill might suddenly lose his mind one day and, if I have to flag him, madness plus "modness" could equal mayhem.

Comment: @Bill: I just flagged your answer to Kev's question.  What happened?

Comment: Bill asked me to flag one of his posts in a comment to this question, but he deleted his comment.

Comment: It turns out Joel Coehoorn deleted Bill's comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15961/will-a-moderator-know-if-i-flag-them/15964#15964

Comment: It's okay, this is for science!

Comment: Sorry, had to flag your comment, Bill.  In the interest of science, of course!

Comment: @raven: Almost anything is excusable when it's done in the name of science. :)

Comment: +1 for the alliteration

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay, I just saw [random](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/9314/random) flag [this post of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15952/is-it-ok-to-turn-your-so-question-answer-into-a-blog-post-and-link-to-it/15957#15957), so yes, we can see flags on our own posts.

I can honestly say you have nothing to worry about, though.  Even if we did something worthy of flagging, I think we're all mature enough to **not** try and get retribution against someone for flagging it.  We were all chosen as moderators (many of us by community vote) at least in part for this reason.

Comment: Hopefully we are cognizant enough to not to try and take actions against ourselves and end up nuking our own content accidentally.

Comment: No, no, no, it was probably some *other* random user.

Comment: If I put myself in the penalty box, I wonder if I still have the privileges to take myself out.  Damn it, the curiosity is going to kill me!

Comment: Bill: If you can't get yourself out, I'll let you out...in a few days...give me enough time to run amok.

Comment: @TheTXI: Okay, if I don't make it back, you're in charge. :)

Comment: Okay, apparently the moderator tools are totally independent of reputation (I knew this already) *and* whether or not you're in the penalty box.  I just suspended myself, then was able to lift my own suspension.  Interesting side note: apparently being released from the penalty box automatically triggers a reputation recalc. :(

Comment: @Bill: Did you set a new record for "recalc ate my rep?"

Comment: The epic question is what will happen if I try to merge TXI's and Bill's user accounts.

Comment: @Tom: LOL! Is there an undo?

Comment: Let me guess. The lizard will eat the pony?

Comment: @Tom Ritter: Do keep in mind that I'm also a moderator on SO. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: I only lost about 150, so I'm nowhere near the record.

Comment: Mod wars. Now THAT's gonna be fun! :))

Comment: @Bill http://sadtrombone.com I fear the rep recalc on SO.  I gotta stay above Jeff =p

Comment: @Tom: I lost > 600 on SO when I recalc'd my own.  Again, the curiosity had gotten to me.

Comment: related Q: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15973

Comment: "...I think we're all mature enough..."  I'm not so sure.  :)

Comment: Excluding known puppetry, the biggest I know for self-inflicted rep shock is 716: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15214#15234. For now... any volunteers?

Answer (score 14):

Oops: flagging Bill the Lizard's "Please flag me to find out." comment as a moderator just deletes it :o

**Update:**
Not only can I flag myself, I can clear my own flag.

Comment: I almost flagged a post of my own but thought better of it. Glad to know I'm not the only one with 'tard tendencies :)

Comment: I see.  So you're the culprit.  I thought Bill just deleted it himself.  Interesting.

Comment: Ok, that explains it. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you think a moderator has done something she shouldn't have done, you can always email `team+sitename@stackexchange.com` and report the matter.

Comment: But then we don't get to do fun experiments.

Comment: Bill: Don't worry. I think Jeff replies: "status-bydesign!"

Comment: I'm too lazy.  I like my retribution to be effortless. :)

Comment: ...in 4-6 weeks ;-p

Comment: @Marc: I thought it's 6-8 weeks...

Comment: My memory must be overly optimistic ;-p

Comment: Are there moderator women?

Answer (score 5):

Even if we went crazy...

- all of the more interesting moderator activities are explicitly logged
- most things can be undone... maybe not through the app, but certainly at the database - for example, user-accounts have been successfully resurrected
- I'm sure Jeff wants to test his backup system eventually...

So we can't do *too* much harm, even if we went postal

Comment: Darn... And here I was hoping :)

Comment: Just to add to this, I *did* accidentally delete the wrong account once (I meant to delete their sock puppet account, open in another tab) and Jeff was able to restore it.

Comment: I was deliberately not naming any names ;-p

Comment: Oh, right.  I missed that little bit of subtlety. :)

Comment: ♦ overflow

Answer (score 3):

The Eye of Sauron (and Bill the Lizard) sees all!

Seriously though, interesting question. I imagine they do because the assumption has been made if someone is a moderator they won't go around posting stuff that needs to be flagged and, if they did, they would act maturely.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure that we can see flags on ourselves. I don't see why there would be any reason why not from a pure logic standpoint.