# What functions are available in the moderator control panel?

Tags: discussion, moderator-abilities

Out of curiosity, what are the functions available on the moderation control panel? Would you mind putting a screenshot or something?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4565/what-facilities-are-there-in-the-moderation-tools

Comment: And a less complete version here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3783/moderator-abilities

Comment: The first link above is for 10K moderators, which I'm sure you're well aware of, considering you passed me in rep on SO a few weeks ago.  The second one has the information you're looking for.

Comment: IIRC, it's more or less the functionality available to people as they work their way up, just in one convenient place.  Can't remember where I read that, though...

Comment: I believe they have the ability to "disappear" inquisitive users...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about asking this in the past, but after more thought I decided not to - it's not for us to know :) Mod-status should remain a mystery to us mortals.

Comment: ...along the lines of *not* letting everyone know too much about their *limitations*.

Comment: Exactly, @rcartaino.