# When I flag a moderator's own content as rude/offensive, will they be able to handle the flag?

Tags: support, flags, offensive

If I flag a moderator's own content as rude/offensive, is there a possibility that very same moderator will handle the flag (i.e. be able to dismiss it), or is it guaranteed another moderator will be handling it?

I'm hoping the answer will be "another moderator handles it", because the ability of a moderator to dismiss flags against themselves when they may be violating community standards would be concerning.

I understand that the idea of flagging a moderator's own content this way is probably pretty serious. Since this is naturally sensitive, I would rather not discuss details to prove I'm not mod-hating, so please take my word that I am treating this seriously.

Previously asked was [Will a moderator know if I flag them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15961/will-a-moderator-know-if-i-flag-them), but this doesn't appear to reflect whether the moderator in question can *do anything* about that flag.

Comment: @Sompuperoo That seems to be a matter of whether they *see* the flag. I want to know if they can *handle* the flag: mainly by declining it. ("Sure, I can do that, I did it in the first place, didn't I?")

Comment: @Sompuperoo Mind posting that as an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All moderator-attention flags are available to be seen by all moderators (and community managers and a few other SE employees, for that matter).  On the sites where I moderate, our moderator teams almost always defer in that case, but on some sites I've seen mods (and CMs) dismiss flags against their own content.  So yes it can happen, and it really comes down to a few factors:

- the degree of conviction on this that any given moderator (or team) operates under
- how clear-cut the situation is (if the flag is *obviously* a troll...)
- whether others are actually around to handle it (especially on small beta sites that don't *need* a lot of moderation, there may be times when only one is available)

In the end, all you can do is decide how much you trust the moderator team in question.  If you think a moderator is abusing flag-handling, your avenues for complaint are the same as for any other concern about moderators: ideally you bring up the issue on meta (with specifics), or if that doesn't work, you can use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page to reach the community team.

Comment: Sometimes I've even deleted my own content in response to a flag (though to be fair, it's mostly obsolete comments).

Comment: @DavidZ yes, if a flag makes me realize my own comment is obsolete or too chatty or something I'll go ahead and accept that, and I think my fellow mods do the same.  I was focusing on the case where the moderator wants to dismiss the flag, since that's the case that can get contentious.  I've seen mods and a CM dismiss flags against their own contributions and it leaves a bad taste (raises questions of objectivity); I don't want to do that.